# Unused and undefined variables in Python with Tkinter, how to fix?

Tags: python-3.x

Essentially what I am running into here is while trying to define a function in Python I am not able to use a variable that I set prior to running the main function. This sounds ambiguous but it will make sense once you see the code.

It works when it isn't defined as a function but that doesn't help because I need it to be a function for use in the tkinter gui.

I expected the code to run if I import the csv and json before running the exportJSON function. I get the error: NameError: name 'csvFilePath' is not defined when doing it this way.

```
def importCSV():
        csvFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
def importJSON():
        jsonFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

#Change fieldname
def exportJSON():
        data = {}
        with open(csvFilePath, 'r') as csvFile:
                csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
                for csvRow in csvReader:
                        ProfileName = csvRow["ProfileName"]
                        data[ProfileName] = csvRow
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
                jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. As it stands right now, it is a syntax error. However, judging by your code, you want to access function local variables from another function - ``exportJSON`` "reads" ``jsonFilePath`` from ``jsonFilePath``. Is this correct?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi hopefully that updated indentation is okay however I still get the error. I want `exportJSON` to read both `csvFilePath` and `jsonFilePath` which are defined by a dialog box in the GUI.

Comment: You might want to read up on how scoping works in Python.

Comment: Note that local variables of functions are not accessible from the outside. You must either pass the data through your program to ``exportJSON``, or store it somewhere accessible to all of them - for example, on a class of which ``importCSV ``, ``importJSON`` and ``exportJSON`` are methods then.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this particular example by simply placing `global` in front of the variable name before defining it. For example:

```
def importCSV():
        global csvFilePath
        csvFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
def importJSON():
        global jsonFilePath
        jsonFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Comment: Using `global` variables is not a good practice. You lose control of who, when and where changes the variable you use. Also your functions naming does not reflect what they do: `importCSV` does not imports CSV, it is only a wraper around `askopenfilename` and should be named accordingly, something like `get_file_path`. While it is totally understandable to you when you are the only person that maintains the code, once you have to collaborate it will create problems. I suggest you read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Style guides are written to make you more productive.

Comment: @igrinis thanks for the pointers means a lot! I will do some reading today.